# Update in SQL Server throws error

Tags: sql-server

I am able to insert a string '1989-06-18' into a SQL Server column of datatype `date`, but when I am trying to update the same column with '2000-01-01' it throws error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is my update query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update
    @id int,
    @title varchar(4),
    @fname varchar(50),
    @lname varchar(50),
    @dob varchar(50),
    @location int,
    @address varchar(255),
    @mobile varchar(10),
    @email varchar(50),
    @experience int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE ResumeMaster
    SET Title = @title,
        FirstName = @fname,
        LastName = @lname,
        DateOfBirth = @dob,
        Location = @location,
        Address = @address,
        mobileNo = @mobile,
        EmailAddress = @email,
        Experience = @experience,
        ModifiedDateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE
        id = @id;
END
```

Comment: use cast keyword to update date.

Comment: DateOfBirth is of type Date and the parameter is varchar since i am concatenating values from three drop down list.

Comment: try Convert(Date,@dob,126)

Comment: @kirankolge thats still not a reason to make it varchar. In fact the .NET type `DateTime` has a ctor which takes a year, a month and a date!

Comment: @SaeedurRehman it doesnt matter how you try to convert a string to a date, if its not a valid date it wont work!

Comment: It is a valid date. Kindly explain why it is not a valid date ?

Comment: I think Convert(Date,@dob,126) is to display the date in a format and will return a string and hence will not solve the purpose.

Comment: @kirankolge try doing a `select @dob` - I guarantee you your date is not what you think it is! if it really was `2001-01-01` then any of these answers would have worked - including doing no cast at all as sql will happily convert a valid string date to a datetime.

Comment: then change your @dob datatype to datetime.

Comment: See sandip's answer, or any of the others and paste that into SSMS, they work fine so your date must be something else

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update

    @id int,
        @title varchar(4),
        @fname varchar(50),
        @lname varchar(50),
        @dob varchar(50),
        @location int,
        @address varchar(255),
        @mobile varchar(10),
        @email varchar(50),
        @experience int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    update ResumeMaster
                        set
                            Title = @title,
                            FirstName = @fname,
                            LastName = @lname,
                            DateOfBirth = Cast(@dob as Date),
                            Location = @location,
                            Address = @address,
                            mobileNo = @mobile,
                            EmailAddress = @email,
                            Experience = @experience,
                            ModifiedDateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                        where id=@id;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore answers about casting your `Varchar(50)` to a `Date` or `DateTime` - they will not solve this issue. The only explanation is that your string `@dob` is not a valid date.

This is why you ensure that parameters to a stored proc match the fields they will be inserting in. change your `@dob` parameter to match the datatype of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CAST** where you assign string as date.

```
SELECT CAST('2000-01-01' AS Date) AS MyDate
```